# Importing Cordova to my Android project

Tags: android, cordova

I am new into android development. I'm start creating native apps and everything's OK until now. But i'm quite curious to go into Cordova-Phonegap development.
I've been reading about how to start but i noticed that in different tutorials some use ruby and others don't.
So how is recommend for me to start developing

Comment: Why would you need any Ruby for Cordova dev ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What tutorials are you talking about? Where did you read that? You doesn't need Ruby at any scenario Windows or Mac in Android development.
Read Official guides: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android